# How to make part of a Bootstrap Dropdown menu scrollable

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a friends requests menu with Bootstrapdrop dowmn menu, i want to make the menu in such a way that the friend requests are scrollable with overflow if they are more than 3, while the li's which contain "you have 2 requests" and "check all requests" stay fixed when scrolling. How do i achieve this as dropdown menus seem to not be easily customizable?

[image]

Comment: paste code here. Screenshots will not help.

Comment: the code is really long mehn

Comment: You can create a fiddle then at jsFiddle, or insert code as snippet.

Comment: done...i have added a lil code snippet. i have actually solved my problem, the issue i have now is shifting the requests to be on the same line with "you have 2 friend requests" and "read more".

Answer (score 2):

Solved the answer....in order to make part of your drop down menu scrollable, you have to create the scrollable content in an

tag tag and apply css(overflow styling to it).

```css
.dropdown-submenu {
    position: relative;
}

.dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
    margin-top: -1px;
}

.dropdown-menu > li{
  
    
   
}


.dropdown-menu > li > ul{
padding-left: 10px;
list-style-type: none;
    height: 100px;
    
    overflow-y:auto;
    overflow-x:hidden;
    left:0px;
    display: block;
}

.dropdown-menu > li > ul > li{
    
    left:0px;
    display: block;
}


ul {


  
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>


<div class="container">
  <h2>My answer</h2>                                         
  <div class="dropdown">
    <button class="btn btn-primary dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">Friends List
    <span class="caret"></span></button>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
    <li><a href="#">you have 10 requests </a></li>
    <li>
    <ul>
      <li><a>Friendx</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend2</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend3</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend4</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend6</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend7</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend8</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Friend9</a></li>
      </ul>
      </li>
      <li><a href="#">read more </a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

this post seems pretty similar to: [Making a drop-down menu scrollable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21983819/making-a-drop-down-menu-scrollable). Have you looked at other people's posts?

Comment: not the same bro, read my question well. i want only a part to be scrollable, u get?

Comment: i have added a lil code snippet. i have actually solved my problem, the issue i have now is shifting the requests to be on the same line with "you have 2 friend requests" and "read more". can u please help me with it??

Answer (score 0):

Place the friend requests in their own div and add 
**max-height**: 120px and
**overflow**: auto.
This should be what you want.

(You can change max-height to whatever height you want, 120px is just an example)

**Example:**

```
.requests {
  max-height: 120px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

Comment: i have added a lil code snippet. i have actually solved my problem, the issue i have now is shifting the requests to be on the same line with "you have 2 friend requests" and "read more", please can u help me with it?

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of how it looks like now?

Comment: i added a snippet

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what exactly you want it to look like. Do you want them all next to each other? If yes use flexbox or display: inline-block

Comment: Can you mark the question as answered by checking the checkmark next to my question? Other users will be able to find the answer easier